# How to implement a method of that class whenever the class is instantiated?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to code a basic star wars game. Currently I have a class:

```
public class LightSaber extends SWEntity {

    public LightSaber(MessageRenderer m) {
        super(m);
        this.shortDescription = "A Lightsaber";
        this.longDescription = "A lightsaber.  Bzzz-whoosh!";
        this.hitpoints = 100000; // start with a nice powerful, sharp axe
        this.addAffordance(new Take(this, m));//add the take affordance so that the LightSaber can be taken by SWActors
    }

    public void canWield(SWActor actor) {
        if (actor.getForcepoints() >= minForcePoints) {
            this.capabilities.add(Capability.WEAPON);// it's a weapon. 
        }
    }

}
```

Basically the `lightsaber` is a weapon if the actor has enough force.However when I instantiate the `lightsaber` class like this:

```
LightSaber bensweapon = new LightSaber(m);
setItemCarried(bensweapon);
```

Obviously the `canWield` method is not called. How do I call that method every time I instantiate the class? Should I create an interface `canWield` and implement it?

---

**EDIT**:Okay here's my `setItemCarried()` code:

```
public void setItemCarried(SWEntityInterface target) {
    this.itemCarried = target;
}
```

Comment: "is not implemented" why ? In LightSaber  class the method seems implemented

Comment: @azro I think OP meant "called".

Comment: Give the code of `setItemCarried()`, it'll surely be into that to add something

Comment: Added the setItemCarried code

Comment: When you create a new instance of `LightSaber` then you need an actor to call that method. Either create an actor within the constructor or pass it as an argument to `LightSaber` then call it , otherwise if you are passing `null` or trying to call without any parameters then it will not work.

Comment: is `setItemCarried` in the `SWActor` class?

Comment: Yes its in the actor class

Comment: I suppose the obvious but not glamorous answer would be to accept an actor in the light saber constructor. The light saber as written now already has a dependency on the actor.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, some `SWEntityInterface` (namely `LightSaber`) objects cannot be wielded by some `SWActor`. And I guess you want to check whether `this` can wield the `SWEntityInterface` before setting it as the item carried.

You should add the method `canWield(SWActor)` to the `SWEntityInterface` and optionally provide a default implementation of returning `true`.

```
interface SWEntityInterface {
    boolean canWield(SWActor actor);
}
```

Now you call this in `setItemCarried`:

```
public void setItemCarried(SWEntityInterface target) {
    if (target.canWield(this)) {
        this.itemCarried = target;
    }
}
```

Note that we didn't change what happens when `LightSaber` is initialised, because it is perfectly ok to create an instance of `LightSaber`. What you are trying to control here is setting something that an `SWActor` can't carry as its `itemCarried`.

Also, consider renaming `canWield` to `canBeWieldedBy`.